# VS2015: "The Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) required by the XAML Designer was not correctly installed." exception with Windows Phone 8.1 XAML

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm trying to update my Win 8.1 app. The designer loads just fine for the `.Winsows` project, but when I try to edit XAML files from the `.WindowsPhone` project I keep getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
The Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) required by the XAML Designer was not correctly installed. Consider repairing your installation of either Visual Studio or the Windows SDK.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I tried reinstalling the 8.1 SDK a few times, no luck. What can be causing this?

Comment: Have you found a remedy?

Answer (score 1):

Recently faced the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise running on Windows 10, attempted cleaning all the caches, reinstalling, manually checking the file permissions and a bit more, only fixed it by following the instructions [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cfdd16a9-6753-4806-96c6-7d07fa8e596f/cant-start-designer-systemsecuritysecurityexception?forum=vssetup), which are for VS2012 but work fine for VS2015.

To make it easier for you (credits to *maeneak* as it's his solution):

- x86, do the following for the ‘Reference Assemblies’ directory in your "Program Files"
- x64, do the following for the 'Reference Assemblies' directory in both 'Program Files' and 'Program Files (x86)'

**This must be done as administrator**

Remember to close all instances of Visual Studio.

1. Select the folder in Windows Explorer, right-click and select
   'Properties'
2. Click the 'Security' tab then click the 'Advanced...' button
3. At the top of the new window there should 'Name' and 'Owner'. Next
   to owner click the 'Change' link.
4. In the new window make sure you have your local computer selected
   under 'From this location:'. If not click 'Locations...' and select
   your local computer, then click 'OK'.
5. In the textbox under 'Enter the object name to select, type 'Users', click 'Check Names...' and Click 'OK'
6. At the top of the page check the option 'Replace owner on
   subcontainers and objects'. Click 'Apply'. You may be prompted to
   shut the properties dialog to apply the ownership changes, if so
   close all dialogs then repeat steps 1 and 2.
7. On the 'Permissions' tab select 'Users' and click 'Edit'.
8. Select 'Full Control' then click 'OK'.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I mistakenly did this on Program Files, should that still apply to Reference assemblies (or could it cause issues doing those permissions at the Program Files level?). As it doesn't seem to have changed anything.